# Access .mdb file in shared drive - only I can see Logon (Name/Password) popup when opening file?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access file (.mdb) that I created an Admin password for. When I try to access the file, I get a Logon popup to enter a Name and Password. Seems to be working just fine for me.

However, I have it saved on a shared drive, and no one else is seeing the Logon popup when they try to access it. They just have free reign of the application, regardless of whether they have the Admin password or not.

Is there something "special" I need to do so that users on other computers can see this? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't set up user level authentication properly.

The prompt for the password is due to [User-level security](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-happened-to-user-level-security-69b362cd-503f-4e8a-a735-fb923ffb9fa3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), a security option that has been deprecated since Access 2007.

The password prompt shows up in two scenario's:

1. Your system workgroup file requires a password
2. You're entering the database using the `/wrkgrp` command-line switch, which is pointing to a workgroup file requiring a password.

With properly set-up user-level security, access to the database is denied if a user doesn't enter using the provided workgroup file, or doesn't enter a valid password.

I recommend you use the latter option, use a separate workgroup file, and the command-line switch for users entering the file. Or better: don't use user-level security at all, but go for a different modality of security (if only one password is enough, encryption is the way to go).